# Create interactive webmap with markers in R using Shiny and Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to create an interactive webmap in R to display locations using Shiny and Leaflet

The idea is that the user selects one input and the markers corresponding to that input(lat/long which are to be fetched from data set of the corresponding input) are displayed in a Leaflet map (with zoom in/out function).
 Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

(sample data file uploaded here):

```
enter code here
Server.R

library(shiny)
library(rpart.plot)
library(leaflet)

shinyServer(
function(input, output) {

output$dtmplot <- renderPlot({
dtmplot <- rpart.plot(dtm, type=4, extra=101)

})
observe({  

output$map <- renderLeaflet( {  
for(j in 1:nrow(df))
{
if(df[j, "col1"]==input$input1) {
map <- leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>% 
addMarkers(lng=df[j,"Longitude"], lat=df[j,"Latitude)
}
}
})
})
}
)


enter code here

UI.R
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
shinyUI(
pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("Sample project"),

sidebarPanel(
plotOutput("dtmplot"),
selectInput("input1", 
label = "label1:",
choices = c(“choice1”,”choice2”),
              selected = " choice1"),
sliderInput("slider","Please select slider input",                min=1,max=100,value=20,step=10) 


  ),


   mainPanel(
   leafletOutput("map")

   )

   ))
```

Comment: Consider redoing your example on the lines of the code available [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) so it's easy to paste it and execute it as one `*.R` file.

Answer (score 0):

The basic code to handle custom points in a leaflet map is available below. The code utilises the official example available [on the leaflet GitHub](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) and provided end-user with the functionality to display custom location on the map.

## `app.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("mymap"),
    p(),
    h1("Added example to add more points here:"),
    p(),
    numericInput("long", label = h3("Longitude:"), value = 11.242828),
    numericInput("lat", label = h3("Latitude:"), value = 30.51470),
    actionButton("recalc", "Show point")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
        cbind(input$long, input$lat)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            setView(lat = 30, lng = 11, zoom = 4) %>%
            addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                             options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
            ) %>%
            addMarkers(data = points())
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Results

The obtained map looks like that:

[image: map]

## Explanation

The mechanics is fairly simple and can be summarised in the following steps:

1. You need to pas `lat` and `lon` to your map to `addMarkers`. In my example this is done via primitive input files but it can be done in a number of ways.
2. You have to decide on the logic of dynamically adding markers to your map; in the presented case this is done with use of an `actionButton`.

---

## *Side notes*

- As at the time of drafting this answer there was no clarity with respect to the actual data that should be represented on the map, I found it more informative to generate the desired functionality following the official example instead of trying to modify the provided code.
- The thing worth noting is that the `lat/lon` values have to be of correct format to appear on the map.
- The map `setView` to make the example more presentable but in an actual solution, default `lat/lon` values should be generated dynamically.

Comment: Can we create interactive maps that is when you click on a map its shows address (like google maps)

Comment: @Supraja Yes, but this is was not mention in your original problem. I understood that the desire was to fetch the coordinates from the data set and plot the corresponding points. You can use mouse events to drive Shiny logic with use of leaflet.

Comment: yeah i dint mention this in the main problem but i just wanted to know whether we can do it or not
Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Supraja No problem, I'm glad to read they you have found the answer helpful.

Comment: Can I get information on the click event in map using R which shows address (like google maps) on leaflet